# How can I adjust door in jamb?

Tags: doors

Since the house was built in 1986 it has settled unevenly.  Drywall cracks I can deal with.  But one problem has me stumped:

I have an exterior door where the top of the opening is now about 3/16 inch too wide, and the bottom of the opening is about 3/8" too wide.  At the strike plate the gap is just under 1/4 inch, which means that the latch isn't holding on by much. **Added:  YES the opening is now a trapezoid**

The house may just be badly built. (  The center of the kitchen/dining room is about 1.5" below the edges, but the grout lines on the stove back splash on the middle of the wall are level.)

That side of the house is on concrete sonotube pylons, presumably down to frost line. After they were set, the tubes were stripped, and the space between infilled with concrete that went down only to ground level.  This is a can of worms I am NOT going to open. It's taken 34 years to get into this shape,it's not going to fall apart next Tuesday.  I'll deal with small problems as they occur.

Checked:  [How can I get my entry door to stay closed?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/59485/how-can-i-get-my-entry-door-to-stay-closed)

This had a good tip about filling holes with toothpicks and glue if you need to move a hole over some small amount.

[Adjusting deadlatch so it doesn't fall into strike pocket](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/126369/adjusting-deadlatch-so-it-doesnt-fall-into-strike-pocket)

Mentions shimming out hinges, but doesn't give much detail on how it's done.

My guess is to do it like this:

- Cut a strip of thin plywood (I have some plywood based wood paneling the width of the hinge.
- Mark the existing location of the jamb hinge on the jamb.
- Remove the jamb hinge.
- Outline the plywood using the hinge as a template.
- Cut out the plywood, and drill holes in the plywood to match the hinge.
- I will need 1 of these at the top, and two at the bottom, if they are 1/8" thick.
- To verify fit first, put in scraps of this plywood on the latch side.  Fasten with brads or double sided tape. Check that I can open the door with them in place.
- Using the original screws, attach the jamb half of the top hinge.  Put the pin in and  verify that the door closes.
- Repeat for bottom hinge.
- Remove screws from top hinge, apply glue to the back of the plywood, put back in place, and use 1/2" longer screws to reattach the top jamb hinge plate.
- Repeat for bottom hinge plate.  If the bottom requires 2 pieces of plywood, glue them together first.
- Verify again that door will open and shut BEFORE THE GLUE DRIES

Tips?  Things I've missed?

Comment: Your description is confusing. Unless the door jamb has actually been expanded (torn apart), margins can't have enlarged. Are they actually tapered (askew)? Please revise your question to clarify. The gap at the strike plate seems appropriate, if on the wide side of the range. 3/16" is about my personal target.

Comment: If you have settling cracks and (most likely) warping of door frame, your band-aid solutions won't help for long.  Fix the settling via foundation repairs or wall-jacks.

Comment: I'd be looking at fixing the door jamb instead of shimming the hinges. You don't want a door out of plum with the jamb., and maybe raise the threshold a bit.

Comment: Jack is right. The better fix is to remove the door and trim and reshim the jamb to get it square. If you don't want to do that you can use hinge shims and weatherstripping. However, you don't have to make your own shims you can buy them for a couple of bucks at your hardware store.        https://www.acehardware.com/departments/building-supplies/lumber-and-trim/shims/5396247?x429=true&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI0ZCtrpeu5gIVIiCtBh0EJwBuEAQYAyABEgLNWPD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds

Comment: Yeah, there's little doubt that the door should be entirely re-set, but I'd like to understand the problem better.

Comment: @HoneyDo  Thanks for the tip on hinge shims.  JACK Fixing the jamb requires finding and removing an unknown number of 4" #12 screws securing the jamb to the frame. Carl If the bandaid sticks 5 years, I'm ok with that. It took 34 years to expand an eighth of an inch.

Comment: Remove the trim, take reciprocating saw with metal blade from top to bottom of rough opening, all screws are found and gone.  Or use a magnet to find the screws and remove them.  Plumb and square your jamb, re-secure.  Re-install door.  I had a door settle on one side by close to an inch leaving it in a similar state.